# read multiple netcdf files - matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, netcdf

I have 40 netcdf files named 'lffd1961_V10M_Iberia.nc', 'lffd1962_V10M_Iberia' ... 'lffd2000_V10M_Iberia'.

I want open all of them in same program, get the same variable in all of them, apply some equation in that variable and create 40 new netcdf files with that variable modified.

To open the 40 files I've developed this code and it works.

```
for yr=1961:2000
inFile=strcat('lffd',num2str(yr),'_V10M_Iberia.nc'); disp(inFile)
nc=netcdf.open(inFile,'NC_NOWRITE');
netcdf.close(nc)
end
```

Now I want get the variable number 4 in all of them. This variable is a 3D matrix (70x51x(8760 or 8784))
Something like this next line but with a 40 years loop:

```
ws_1961(1962, etc, etc) = netcdf.getVar(nc,4);
```

and it's supposed to have 40 new variables in my workspace.
After this I want to apply this equation in all of that 40 variables:

```
ws_80 = ws.*(log(z/alpha)/log(exp(1))/(log(10/alpha)/log(exp(1))));
```

and finally create 40 new netcdf files with my new variable in each file.

something like that:

```
outFile=strcat('year',num2str(yr),'_80m.nc')
ncid = netcdf.create(outFile,'CLOBBER');

dimid0 = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'longitude',nlon); % getvar number 1
dimid1 = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'latitude',nlat); %getvar number 2
dimid2 = netcdf.defDim(ncid,'time',nt); %getvar number 3

varid0 = netcdf.defVar(ncid,'longitude','double', dimid0);
varid1 = netcdf.defVar(ncid,'latitude','double', dimid1);
varid2 = netcdf.defVar(ncid,'time','double', dimid2);
varid3 = netcdf.defVar(ncid,'ws_80','double', [dimid0 dimid1 dimid2]);

netcdf.putAtt(ncid,varid0,'units','degrees_east');
netcdf.putAtt(ncid,varid0,'long_name','longitude');

netcdf.putAtt(ncid,varid1,'units','degrees_north');
netcdf.putAtt(ncid,varid1,'degrees_north','latitude');

netcdf.endDef(ncid);

netcdf.putVar(ncid,varid0,longitude);
netcdf.putVar(ncid,varid1,latitude);
netcdf.putVar(ncid,varid2,time);
netcdf.putVar(ncid,varid3,ws80);
```

It's hard for me to explain this in a way that all of you understand so please be confortable to ask whatever you want.

Comment: At which part are you stuck and need help?. It is not clear to me if your equation requires all the data from all files in one variable. If not, you are better off working with one file at a time (read, apply equation, write). Using higher level functions like ncread, ncinfo, ncwriteschema and ncwrite would probably be easier.

Comment: could you please help me by parts?
My first loop, that opens all my .nc files works fine.
Now I need some kind a loop to get all the variables in the fourth position 'netcdf.getVar(nc,4);' at each file.
My next step consist in have 40 variables (one of each file) in my workspace.

Comment: Does your version have the ncread function? And again, do you really need all 40 variables to apply the equation? Or can you apply the equation to one variable at a time?

Comment: yes, my version has that function.
I don't need the 40 variables to apply the equation. I need to apply the equation at those 40 variables. So, yes, I can apply the equation to one variable at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some 'air code' to get you started.

```
% The variable we want to process
myVarName = 'ws_80';

for yr=1961:2000
  inFile  = strcat('lffd',num2str(yr),'_V10M_Iberia.nc'); 
  disp(inFile);
  outFile = strcat('lffd',num2str(yr),'_V10M_Iberia_processed.nc'); 
  disp(outFile);

  % copy input file to create a template for the output
  copyDone = copyfile(inFile, outFile,'f');
  if(~copyDone)
      error('Could not copy file');
  end

  % Read variable
  inVar = ncread(inFile,myVarName);

  % Replace this line with your equation
  outVar = myProcessFunction(inVar);

  % Write variable
  ncwrite(outFile, myVarName, outVar);

end
```

You will have to modify this to suite your goal. Give it a try and post back on where you get stuck.

Comment: your 'air code' answered exactly to all my needs.
Thank you very much. I'm very grateful to you.